# CSS Overriding Accordion Causing Dark Mode

Tags: html, css, components, tailwind-css, flowbite

I'm using an accordion component from Flowbite. I'm having trouble figuring out what's causing the accordion to go into dark mode on page load. I did inspect element and saw its some dark mode CSS that comes with Flowbite. I downloaded that CSS into a file and manually removed the CSS I found from inspect element but the accordion is still dark. On the Flowbite site you can copy code in light mode or dark mode as well and I re-copied it multiple times to ensure I didn't chose the wrong setting. I've checked the CSS file, my HTML and inspect element but I'm still having trouble.

I want the accordion to stay the light gray color on load, not the dark mode shown in the picture. Here are some screenshots.

*Note: I've also tried clearing web cache. If I turn off dark mode, the issue is fixed but I've used other components from the site and they don't cause this issue, so I don't understand what's different with this accordion.

[image: Dark Mode Accordion]

[image: CSS]

[image: CSS Causing Problem from Inspect Element]

```
 <div id="accordion-open" data-accordion="open" class="mx-auto mt-6 mb-10">
                         <h2 id="accordion-open-heading-1">
                           <button type="button" class=" flex items-center justify-between w-full p-5 font-medium text-left border border-gray-200 rounded-t-xl focus:ring-4 focus:ring-gray-200   hover:bg-gray-100  bg-gray-100 " data-accordion-target="#accordion-open-body-1" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="accordion-open-body-1">
                             <span class="flex items-center">Activity Diagram (click to open/close)</span>
                             <svg data-accordion-icon="" class="w-6 h-6 rotate-180 shrink-0" fill="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 20 20" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M5.293 7.293a1 1 0 011.414 0L10 10.586l3.293-3.293a1 1 0 111.414 1.414l-4 4a1 1 0 01-1.414 0l-4-4a1 1 0 010-1.414z" clip-rule="evenodd"></path></svg>
                           </button>
                         </h2>
                         <div id="accordion-open-body-1" class="" aria-labelledby="accordion-open-heading-1">
                           <div class="p-5 font-light border-b-2 border-gray-200  border border-b-3 border-gray-200 rounded-b-xl focus:ring-4 focus:ring-gray-200">
                            <img class="pt-6 object-scale-down h-full w-full mx-auto px-28" src="">     
                         </div>
                         </div>
                       </div>
```

Comment: looks to me like its using your system preference to determine the dark mode. I'm not super familiar with that style media query however so I could be wrong.

Comment: If I turn off dark mode, it fixes the issue but my problem is that I've used other components from the site as well and none of them do this. So I don't understand whats different about the accordion that could be causing it. @JDawwgy

Comment: on the right of the dev tools inspector where it lists the class' that are being applied it should also tell you what file those classes came from, you could see if you can track down the media query and rip it out of your codebase

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem,

I set darkMode to class in my tailwindcss.config.js

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: ["./**/*.html", "./js/**/*.js"],
  darkMode: 'class',
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

and then added the below to the head section of my html page:

```
<meta name="color-scheme" content="light">
```

and boom, the grey text issue on my accordions showing after one is expanded dissapeared...

But for a good while I didnt twig that the colour change in the accordion text was due to my mac auto changing the system settings to darkmode in the evenings... and flowbite picking this setting up as I had not enabled darkmode in my project within tailwind at all...